# Not all inputs disabled but not getting POST data

Tags: php, jquery, forms, disabled-input

I have a form...I want to add disabled to all the inputs inside a certain div but rest of the form. I verified that this is indeed happening as it should but, when I submit the form with the disables added, I get no POST data. But with all my code the same, except for not adding the disableds, I do get my post data as I should. And I repeat, I DID verify that the disableds are only going on the inputs that I expect and NOT the other inputs that I want data from.

There is not really even much code..the inputs look like this (and it is definitely inside a form element) -

```
 <div class="abridged-hide">
 <input type="hidden" name="actor_id[]" value="162705079">
 </div>
```

The submit button -

```
<button type="submit" id="entry_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Page</button>
```

Jquery is simply -

```
$('#entry_submit').on('click', function(event){
    $('.abridged-hide input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.unabridged-hide input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

I tried

```
.attr('disabled', true);
.prop('disabled', true);
```

Like I said, if I comment out the Jquery and submit, I do get my post data fine, something about this Jquery is making me not get my post and really don't see any reason why... Thanks in advance.

edit - these are the inputs being created dynamically.

```
<td class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical" aria-hidden="true">
<input type="hidden" name="actor_id[]" value="162705079">
</span> Julie Benz - J</td>
```

edit - code that generates the inputs

```
$( ".drop-container" ).droppable({
 accept: ".draggable",
 addClasses: false,
 drop: function(event, ui) {
    var drag_name = ui.draggable.html();
    ui.draggable.hide();
    var new_body_count = '<tr><td class="btn btn-primary">'+drag_name+'</td>
   <td class="badge"><input placeholder="Number of Kills" name="body_count" class="number-count" type="number"></td></tr>'
$('.table').prepend(new_body_count);
  }
  });
```

Comment: Is the form itself being submitted but you're not getting on post data? Or does the form not submit at all?

Comment: I think depending on the browser, disabled inputs aren't sent. Use readonly.

Comment: I should mention...the form items that are being submitted that are not being disabled are being created dynamically after the page loads...I don't know if that might have something to do with it. I AM getting POST data from the form, so actually now that I think about it, I think it is not the disabled at all but something to with the elements being created dynamically.

Comment: I have added the html for the dynamically created inputs. ...I don't see anything there that should not work though.

Comment: you need to `return true;` on your button, or force the form to submit ie `$('form').submit();`

Comment: Your jquery button isn't submitting your form.

Comment: return true or .submit() did not do it. The form should and does submit because I do not have anything like preventDefault to prevent it. I get the post data from other form items that are NOT generated dynamically. It is only the items that are created dynamically after page load. ...it has to be something with that. ...I am not sure what yet.

Comment: The disabled stuff all seems to be fine...I get those items in post if I don't disable them and still don't get those other items. ...must be because they are generated automatically...I can post the code for that.

Comment: Did you try my answer ? is it work or not ?

Comment: i have added the code that generates the input elements. ...it is using Jquery-ui...when one element is dragged and dropped it creates a new element and then hides the initial dragged element. And then when I submit the form, I am trying to disable the draggable elements. I need the draggable elements to exist because I use that to create a new copy of them elsewhere after they are dragged.

Comment: yes EnginnerCoder I did. That did not work. They are being selected fine, I have tested this.

Comment: Why are you disabling hidden elements? Could you not just set their value to 0?

Comment: Well the question has kind of changed. It seems that the problem really has nothing to do with the disabling messing things up, seems that for some reason the dynamically created inputs are not getting posted. ...but I verified they are inside of the form. Am I adding them to the DOM the wrong way or something that they are not getting processed..ie somehow not actually in the DOM (not sure the best terminology here).

Comment: OK... so in terms of good StackOverflow etiquette you should probably delete this question and re-open another one with the correct problem. In terms of your code issue - are they in the form? Are you using something like Firebug or Developer Tools to look at what's being submitted?

Comment: I remade the question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244046/jquery-dynamically-created-inputs-not-posting