# Jquery dynamically created inputs not posting

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form that has inputs being created dynamically with Jquery. If I hardcode an element exactly like it is being created with Jquery, I get the POST data fine. But when the elements are created dynamically, they do not submit their POST data.

The Jquery for creating the elements (using Jquery-UI to drag and drop an element, when it is dropped it creates a new element in that area).

```
$(".drop-container").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    addClasses: false,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var drag_name = ui.draggable.html();
        ui.draggable.hide();
        var new_body_count = '<tr><td class="btn btn-primary">' + drag_name + '</td><td class="badge"><input placeholder="Number of Kills" name="body_count" class="number-count" type="number"></td></tr>'
        $('.table').prepend(new_body_count)
    }
});
```

The HTML that it creates -

```
<tr>
    <td class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical" aria-hidden="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="actor_id[]" value="162705079">
        </span>
        Julie Benz - J
    </td>
    <td class="badge">
        <input placeholder="Number of Kills" name="body_count" class="number-count" type="number">
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is definitely inside of the form tag. Like I said, if I hardcode the html, it POSTS fine, but when the inputs are created by Jquery, no post. I am quite sure something to do with it being dynamically created.

edit -

```
$('#update_form').on('submit', 'form', function(){
     $('.abridged-hide input').attr('disabled', true);
     $('.unabridged-hide input').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

edit - the code for the HTML form

```
<legend class="text-center">Film title: <?=$film_title_text?></legend>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <?=form_open('update/add_category');?>
        <label for="category">Category Title</label>
        <?=form_input($cat_title, '');?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Category</button> 
    <?=form_close();?>
</div>
<div id="event_form" class="col-md-6">
    <?=form_open('/update/save_entry', $update_id);?>
    <?php if(isset($thenav['nav_id'])){?>
        <input type="hidden" name="film_id" value="<?=$q?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="add_category">Add Category</label>
            <?=form_dropdown('cat_id', $cat, '', $cat_id );?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="heading">Article Title</label>
           <?=form_input($title, '');?>
        </div>
        <div class="well">
             <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="heading">Add Custom Body Count Field</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="body_count">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="custom_body_cnt">Add Custom Body Count Field</button>
             </div>     
         </div>
         <div class="panel panel-primary">
             <div class="panel-heading">Abridged Cast</div>
         <div class="panel-body abridged-hide">
    <?php 
    foreach ($this_actors as $this_actor['name']) {
        $characters = $this_actor['name']->name;
        if(isset($characters[0])){
            $characters = $characters[0];
        }else{
            $characters = '';
        }
        echo "<span class='btn btn-primary draggable'><input type='hidden' class='actor_field' name='actor_id[]' value='".$this_actor['name']->id."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical' aria-hidden='true'></span> ".$this_actor['name']->name." - ".$characters."</span>";
    }?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="slide-abridged" class="btn wide-button"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Unabridged Cast</div>
         <button id="slide-unabridged" class="btn wide-button"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
        <div class="panel-body unabridged-hide">
    <?php 
    foreach ($unabridged_actors as $this_actor['name']) {
        $characters = $this_actor['name']->characters;
        if(isset($characters[0])){
            $characters = $characters[0];
        }else{
            $characters = '';
        }
        echo "<input type='text' name='actor_name' value='".$this_actor['name']->id."'>";
        echo "<span class='btn btn-primary draggable'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical' aria-hidden='true'></span> ".$this_actor['name']->name." - ".$characters."</span>";
    }?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="slide-unabridged" class="btn wide-button"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
    <?=form_textarea($article, '');?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="label label-default">Body Count Inventory</span>
        <div class="well drop-container clearfix">
            <table class="table">               
                <tr>
                    <td class="btn btn-primary">Total</td>
                    <td class="badge"><input placeholder="Number of Kills" name="film_total" class="film_total" disabled type="number"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
       <button type="submit" id="entry_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Page</button>
<?php }?>

<?=form_close()?>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the dot in `$('.table')`? You're saying get all elements with class name *"table"*. This alone works for me `$('table').prepend(new_body_count)` on a table element. Notice I removed the dot.

Comment: No, it is actually a class on it named table. ...probably a bad choice of class names. It does do the prepending where I want it to go just fine.

Answer (score 0):

*I'd like to ask you for some more details, but stack overflow won't let me.*

Anyways, if you're handling the POST on a submit event through jQuery, chances are that you're not binding the event to dynamically added forms.

For example, if you bind the event to forms this way:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
    //do POST stuff
})
```

It will only attach the event to forms that were in the DOM at the time you bind the event.

In order to bind events to dynamic elements, you must do it through a non-dynamic element. For example, let's say your forms are wrapped inside a div with id `forms-container`. Then you could attach the event like this:

```
$("#forms-container").on("submit", "form", function(){
    //do POST stuff
})
```

This way the event would be attached to all elements inside `#forms-container`, including the ones which are dynamically added.

Comment: The POST is all handled by PHP on another page. But I do need to do disable some other items before submit... if you see my edit, I tried that but it does not do the disabling and it does not post the dynamic elements still.

Comment: I have read the Jquery docs and delegation...and it is exactly like you suggested jrlainfiesta. I have created a div outside of the form and referenced it like so..it seems I could get the values out of dynamically created elements but I still cannot access them from PHP. I suppose I should be able to do AJAX but I would really prefer to use just PHP.

Comment: Well, I'm still unsure about how you're doing things. Could you edit your question to include how you're making your html form?

Comment: I have added my exact code. It is kind of a lot to decipher, a lot of it is being generated by php (i am using codeigniter frameword, I did not include the form variables in the edit code). The dynamic code that gets generated is from the javascript in the top of my post. When you drop and item from drag and drop, you can see it prepends it to .table. And that all works fine, and it shows up. ...I speculate the Jquery is not bubbling up/delegating properly. I ruled out bad HTML messing up because if I hard code it EXACTLY like it gets generated, it does post fine like it should.

Comment: At one point, I did remove the other form that is on this page, leaving only the form in question, and I did wrap it in a div and use the .on code from above. ...just like it shows in jquery docs. ...when I post, ALL other form POST variables show up in inspector...EXCEPT the generated inputs. ...but again, if I hardcode them, they do indeed show up in post.

Comment: Oddly though, using .on, I have been able to get .val() from the dynamically generated inputs. But, it will not post them.

Comment: I need to get this working ASAP though. If anything, I need some kind of workaround. ...I am able to use .each and iterate through the dynamic post values...could I put those in an array, then post the array with ajax on submit and add it into the rest of the form values? (but not passing the other values using ajax).

Comment: A regular form should just POST all the values it has at the time it's submitted, no matter whether they were added dynamically. I don't know if CodeIgniter does something weird though.

If you're willing to send the form through AJAX, you can serialize all the values and post them to your backend using jQuery. I don't think it's a good idea to send some data through AJAX but not other, at least not from the same form (and it'd be quite complicated).

Comment: Well...I have slept, maybe I will see something I overlooked yesterday, but I just don't get why the whole .on delegation thing is not working. I have a feeling it is something dumb and small I am overlooking. I will post it on here whenever I figure it out though.

Comment: Well, I think maybe I was just sleep deprived yesterday because now I got it working quite quickly. Turns out...all that pain and suffering because of bad HTML. I must have had some DIVs jacked up because I took out the column divs that I had in place, submitted the form using .on delegating down. Works fine. So I guess the lesson to be learned here...don't make crappy HTML lol.

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, it was a delegation issue, but I still don't quite understand it.

This works -

```
$('#reg_form').on('submit', function(event){
    var address = $('input[name=address]').val();
    var city = $('input[name=city]').val();
    var state = $('select[name=state]').val();
    var zip = $('input[name=zip]').val();
   var format_address = address + '+' + city + '+' + state + '+' + zip;
   var password = $('input[name=password]').val();
   var password_verify = $('input[name=confirm_password]').val();
   var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
   var confirm_email = $('input[name=confirm_email]').val();
   if(email != confirm_email){
       event.preventDefault();
       $('.text-danger').show();
       $('.text-danger').html('Email Address does not match.');
  }
  if(password != password_verify)
 {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.text-danger').show();
    $('.text-danger').html('Password does not match.');
 }
//call google maps api 
$.getJSON( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + format_address, function( data ) {
  console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
  console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
//populate form fields    
  $('input[name=lat]').val(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
  $('input[name=lng]').val(data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
  });

  $(this).unbind('submit');
});
```

If I take out that unbind, the form does not post the dynamically generated values. I had tried a few things likes doing this in the very beginning -

```
$('.form_container').on('submit', 'form', function(event){
```

and I tried a few other things can't thing of right now..binding preventdefault, unbinding preventdefault.

But like I said, this above code with the unbind works. Maybe someone who knows about about binding and delegation more than me can weigh in on it.